# Adjusting elements (submit button, custom button)

Tags: html, css

I have a few problems with my current `html` page. I have a "back" and "continue" Button. The back button should just go to the previous page, the continue button should submit the form.

I want to adjust the Back-Button on the left side of the input field with class `inputfld`, and the Continue Button on the right side of the `inputfld`. Alternative its also okay, when both buttons are adjusted in the middle of input field, but in the same row: [image: here].

Furthermore, I have currently the problem, that the buttons have different sizes (*width*), but I dont know why. & is there are way that I can use the hover, active from the back button for the Continue-Button?

```css
        .contentarea {
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        padding-left: 50%
        padding-right: 50%;
        padding-bottom: 18px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        }
        .content-header {
          font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          font-weight:700;
        }
        .input-header{
          font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
        }
        input[type=submit].continueButton {
         float: right;
            width: 100px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: visible;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
         display: block;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            margin: auto;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
            font:11px/normal sans-serif;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            background-color: #ececec;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            -moz-background-clip: padding; /* for Firefox 3.6 */
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border-radius: 0.2em;
            display: block;
            margin-right: 5px;
            /* IE hacks */
            zoom: 1;
         }
        .backButton {
          width: 76px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: visible;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
         display: block;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            margin: auto;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
            font:11px/normal sans-serif;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            background-color: #ececec;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
            -moz-background-clip: padding; /* for Firefox 3.6 */
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border-radius: 0.2em;
            display: block;
         float: right;
            margin-right: 5px;
            /* IE hacks */
            zoom: 1;
        }
        .backButton:hover,
        .backButton:active {
            border-color: #3072b3;
            border-bottom-color: #2a65a0;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #3c8dde;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#599bdc), to(#3072b3));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
        }
        .floated {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right:5px;
        }
    
   input[type=text].inputfld{
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset, 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
      transition: all 0.2s linear;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #222222;
      position: relative;
      height: 30px;
      width: 250px;
      margin-left: 7px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      display: inline-block; 
      margin-top: 5px;
      opacity: 8;
    
      &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #999999;
      }
      
      &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999999;
      }
    
      &:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #3498db inset, 0 -1px 0 #3498db inset, 1px 0 0 #3498db inset, -1px 0 0 #3498db inset, 0 0 4px rgba(35,146,243,0.5);
        outline: none;
        background: url(../img/keyIcon.png) 12px 11px no-repeat, #FFF;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="contentarea">
 <p class="content-header"> [XX] XXXXXXXXXXXX </p>
    <span class="input-header">XXXXXXXXX:</span>

   <form>
      <input type="text"  class="inputfld" autofocus />
        <a href="index.html" class="backButton floated">Back</a>
       <input type="submit" class="continueButton floated"  value="Continue" />  
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: The buttons have different sizes because the 'Back' button is an anchor and "Continue" button is a input type button. Also your code is messy. Can you post a link to the webpage?

Comment: I have edited my code, now you are able to execute the source.

Comment: Why do you have the back button after the text input in your HTML?

Comment: just that the back button is on the left side, and the continue button on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the continue button on the right side of inputfld, by simply adding `float: right;` to it.

The different widths are caused by the element type (a - input):

- The input renders it as 100px in total (76px (*content*) + 2*11px (*padding*) 2*1px (*border*) = **100px**)
- The anchor renders it as 100px content-width and add the padding and border width later on (100px (*content*) + 2*11px (*padding*) + 2*1px (*border*) = **124px**).

**CSS changes:**

```
input[type=submit].continueButton {
  float: right;
}
.backButton {
  width: 76px;
  /*
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 11px;
    width: calc(100px - 2*11px - 2*1px);
  */
}
```

There are multiple ways to line the buttons with the inputfld up:

- **Margin** add a margin of 25px to each button (300px (*container*) - 250px (*inputfld*) = 50px / 2 = **25px** on each side)
- **Change the container size (in the snipped)** to 250px (same as inputfld) and the left and right would line up with the buttons.
- **Absolute positioning** add `position: absolute;` and `left: 25px` (almost the same as the first one)

**Hover effect:**

You don't even have a hover effect for your button (?!?), so add `input[type="submit"].continueButton:*****` to the `.backButton` hover effect and add `!important` (I guess there is no better way).

```css
.contentarea {
    width: 255px;    /*CHANGED (250px + 5px padding(-left) in inputfld)*/
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding-right: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.content-header {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:700;
}
.input-header{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=submit].continueButton {
    float: right;    /*CHANGED*/
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;    /*<=== change/delete top+bottom margin (first parameter), when your change the height*/
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    margin: 0;    /*CHANGED*/
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
    font:11px/normal sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ececec;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    -moz-background-clip: padding; /* for Firefox 3.6 */
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0; /*CHANGED*/
    /* IE hacks */
    zoom: 1;
}
.backButton {
    width: 76px;    /*CHANGED*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
    font:11px/normal sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ececec;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
    -moz-background-clip: padding; /* for Firefox 3.6 */
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    /* IE hacks */
    zoom: 1;
}
/*CHANGED: .continueButton and "!important" added*/
.backButton:hover,
.backButton:active,
input[type=submit].continueButton:hover,
input[type=submit].continueButton:active {
    border-color: #3072b3 !important;
    border-bottom-color: #2a65a0 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #3c8dde !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#599bdc), to(#3072b3)) !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3) !important;
}
.floated {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:5px;
}
input[type=text].inputfld{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset, 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 0;    /*CHANGED*/
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 8;

    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #999999;
    }

    &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999999;
    }

    &:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #3498db inset, 0 -1px 0 #3498db inset, 1px 0 0 #3498db inset, -1px 0 0 #3498db inset, 0 0 4px             rgba(35,146,243,0.5);
        outline: none;
        background: url(../img/keyIcon.png) 12px 11px no-repeat, #FFF;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentarea">
  <p class="content-header"> [XX] XXXXXXXXXXXX </p>
  <span class="input-header">XXXXXXXXX:</span>
  <form>
    <input type="text"  class="inputfld" autofocus />
    <a href="index.html" class="backButton floated">Back</a>
    <input type="submit" class="continueButton floated"  value="Continue" />  
  </form>
</div>
```

**Tipp:**

You should write your code more clearly, I saw multiple settings for one property (margin was set twice in .contineButton), unnecessary settings (also margin) and the code was kind of messed up, but you use comments, which is great.

Hope I could help *-Minding*

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer/explanation. I have added your code, the size (width) is now correct. But it still not adjusted to the left and right of the input field. Maybe when this is to hard, it would be also okay, when both are in the middle of the inputfield.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Fa4we3Q.png , the above one would be ideal, but I'm also statisfied with the second one.

Comment: @Matej The snipped works now, if something is wrong, just tell me. _-Minding_

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you could also solve the problem with the hover, active for the continueButton, then I can mark this question as "solved my problem" :)

Comment: Sorry, I have a little additional question, I have noticed that the buttonBack Button is a bit to small (height). After I have set the height to 30px - the text is wrong aligned. I have tested several things, but I dont get it. Would be great, when you could add this to your answer.

Comment: @Matej I've added a comment in the 5th line of the 4th block in the snipped. _-Minding_

Comment: Thanks, but I have the problem with the backButton :) Tried to use the same on the backButton , but seems not working.